# Compressing data frames in R

Tags: r

Is there any method to compress data frame in R. I have an external file which I want to import into a data frame. But, since the data is large, it would result in a memory error. Although I am not sure if compression makes sense in R since it uses RAM memory for creating data structures, but it would really help me if anything synonymous to compression can be used.

Comment: Look at this [CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Comment: I think the short answer is "no", but the long answer is that the page @Roland's comment points to provides lots of strategies for dealing with large data in R.

Comment: @Kunal Please could you state how large your data file is?  It would help to know this basic fact before proceeding. And how much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's too late to answer this question, but I thought I better share some recent work in R that allows compressing data frames. Currently, there is a package in R called `fst` ([Lightning Fast Serialization of Data Frames for R)](http://www.fstpackage.org/)
 , in which you can create compressed `fst` objects for your data frame. A detailed explanation can be found in the [fst-package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fst/fst.pdf), but I'll briefly explain how to use it and how much space an `fst` object takes. First, Let's create a data frame with some data and then check the size of this data frame, as follows:

```
install.packages("pryr") # for object_size()
library(pryr)
N <- 1000 * 8
M <- 100
df <- data.frame(A = c(rep(strrep("A", M), N), rep(strrep("B", N), N)))
object_size(df)
# 73.3 kB
```

Now, let's convert this dataframe into an `fst` object, as follows:

```
install.packages("fst") #install the package
library(fst) #load the package
path <- paste0(tempfile(), ".fst") #create a temporary '.fst' file
write_fst(df, path) #write the dataframe into the '.fst' file
ft <- fst(path) #load the data as an fst object
object_size(ft)
# 2.14 kB
```

The disk space for the created `.fst` file is `434 bytes`. You can deal with the `ft` object as a normal data frame (as far as I tried).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `data.table` package stores data similar to data frames but with some added efficiencies, this may compress your data sufficiently.

The more general solution would be to load your data into a database instead of directly into R, then pull just the pieces that you need from the database, the sqldf and RSQLite packages may be of help.  There used to be a package called SQLiteDF that made this process transparent (the data was in a database, but you had an object in R that looked and acted like a data frame but pulled the data from the data base).  There are archived copies of the package available through CRAN, but some work would probably be needed to get it working with recent versions of R (the latest version of the package was in 2009).

There are other tools on the CRAN Task View page mentioned in the comments (scroll down to the "Large Memory" section) that discuss some other possibilities and how to analyze data that is to large to work with in RAM.

Comment: `data.table` doesn't compress data. Since Kunal is a new user we should probably check the basics first; e.g., how large is their large.

Comment: The data frame is quite big around 18 GB. And I am sure R would not be able to allocate this big chunk of contiguous memory. Also, this data frame would keep on increasing in size as per my process.

Comment: @MatthewDowle, you are correct that `data.table` does not compress, I believe that it makes fewer copies when editing which can be useful for datasets that fit in memory, but take up most of it.  In this case the original poster will need to use the other suggestions.

Comment: @KunalBatra Thanks. Where did the 18GB figure come from? It can't be the result of `object.size()` because you haven't loaded the data yet.  Is it the size of the text file on disk? If so that's usually not a good measure of what you need in RAM. Would be great if you could next tell us how many rows (`wc -l`) and how many columns are in the file.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: I have created a process in which there are some cross joins happening which result in such huge amount of data. Since, I canot load this amount of data into R, I am trying to find out if I can load that data in an incremental process from database into R and do the futher processing. But, for that I am not able to find out if there is a way where I can join a R dataframe and mysql table with each other. I dont think sqldf allows that. I have also created a separate thread asking this question but havent got an answer yet.

Comment: @KunalBatra Suggest you seek local training, paid support or employ a consultant to complete your project. This seems to be a merry dance up the garden path. So there is no external file, is there.

Comment: This data is present in DB. I want to import this data from DB into R data frame based upon a variable which is common to this table and a data frame already present in R. Is it possible?

Comment: @KunalBatra I've already said "I believe what you asked is possible but I personally don't know." in my comment to your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13452711/403310). I also gave you information and advice there on how you might improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: Thankyou Matt. I am afraid thats a bit of challenge for me getting any external help. And I am afraid google could not help me out as well :). I am a bit stuck. probably will have to find some other way of implementing this.

Comment: @KunalBatra Ok if external options are ruled out, then currently, you're left with my advice in the other question, which you don't appear to have followed yet.

Comment: But with Rsqlite, can you perform any operation offered by R or any package directly? Or you can only run the functions that SQlite has implemented?
(without needing to break the data on small pieces).
For example I want to run a regression on a 50GB numeric file or calculate the median. Or I want to apply DBScan, or just want to create another vector where each elements is expressed as some operation with the old ones BB[i]=AA[i]*AA[i-1]+AA[i-2].  Can I do this with R and Rsqlite (or any other DB connector)?

Comment: @skan, I think that Rsqlite would only allow you to pull in parts of your data (you would need to import explicitly) then you would process the results in R (if they all fit in memory).  The ff package has ways to have a something that acts like a data frame but is stored on the disk drive.  The dplyr package will translate R into SQL so that the database does much of the work, but you use the same commands as in R, the biglm package is used for computing regressions on datasets that do not fit in memory.

Comment: I think we need a "universal" solution that just works transparently by making R believe that the memory is infinite and allowing the user to use any package through it. (Instead of solutions that try to rewrite common functions). As far as I know SPSS can work with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large data frame than ff package might help you to store your large data with a smaller size. 
Try to look ff package which is available on CRAN