# How can I compress a .RData file which is a large data frame?

Tags: compression, rstudio, gzip, workspace, rdata

everybody!

I have a 50MB .RData file which is one large data frame. Can I compress it to 20-25MB somehow? I tried .zip and .gz, but the former almost did nothing and the latter even generated a bigger file.

Also, what's the most space-efficient way to export the workspace in RStudio? Again, using .RData generates a massive file, and I wonder if I can make it smaller.

Anybody with more experience? Thank you very much!

Comment: I have very limited knowledge of RStudio, did a quick read of some material.  If the RStudio program already compresses the file saved you will find it difficult to compress further.  What are the first 5-10 bytes of the .RData file.   If the data can be Pre / Post processed (looks like the API allows you to apply before and after processing)  to save / Retrieve via an external program, it  "MIGHT" be able to be compressed . (assuming Lossless compression).   changing how the original  RData is saved, the post processed for compression , then pre-process for retrieval might help.

Comment: Also note: The type of data to be compressed will determine if it can be compressed at all.  IE: random data, compression most likely not possible , or limited..  Try saving it in "A" ASCII format , then try the compression. maybe binary "X" mode mangles it to much. interesting article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/efficiently-saving-and-sharing-data-in-r/

Comment: Thanks! @PhillipWilliams I figured it's a long shot.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396603/compressing-data-frames-in-r

Comment: Hi @PawinData! I'm currently having the same trouble as you did some time ago. Did you manage to find a solution? Thanks :)